# ViewPager and YouTube API

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, youtube-api

I need to develop application contains multiple screens, each one contain either video and pic or pic only.. swing between this screens every time interval

hint: the user should not interact with the video by stopping it or other

I try to use view pager with YouTube player API, But each video work for a few seconds then stop and throw this warning

"YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of the player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by com.google.android.youtube.player"

attached screenshots of my code.

I search a lot about this problem but I don't get the solution
attached screens of my code

I try to build this without view pager  by using fragments and  swiping between fragments using timer ..but also get the same problem

I also try to use web view but cannot handle the hint said before

is there any solution of viewPager problem, or another idea to build this app?

this is my main activity

```
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        pagerchangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                mPagerAdapter.onPageChanged(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        };
        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pagerchangeListener);
```

viewPager adapter method:

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if (data.get(position).getVideo() == null) {

                ImageFragment imageFragment = new ImageFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("IMAGE_URL", data.get(position).getImage());
                imageFragment.setArguments(args);
                return imageFragment;
            } else {

                Log.i("tag3", "getItem video" + String.valueOf(position));
                VideoFragment videoFragment =
                        VideoFragment.newInstance(data.get(position).getVideo(), data.get(position).getImage());
                listenerMap.put(position, videoFragment.getmInitializeListener());
                return videoFragment;

            }

        }
```

constructor of video fragment:

```
public VideoFragment() {
        super();
        setRetainInstance(true);
        mInitializeListener = new InitializeListener() {
            @Override
            public void startVideo() {
                if (getUserVisibleHint())
                    initYoutube();
            }

            @Override
            public void stopVideo() {
                if (youTubePlayer1 != null)
                    youTubePlayer1.release();

            }
        };
    }
```

xml of vedio fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.newConcept.education.galleryApp.fragment.VideoFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/VideoFragment_youtube_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/VideoFragment_imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when your "overlay" your YoutubeFragment with other view like your imageview. One posible solution is if you can hide the imageview when your video is playing and you don´t see this warning anymore. Only put when video start:

```
videoFragmentImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Also check if you don´t have other view in front of the player like FloatingActionButton or other else, hide this views. Tell us if this works

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I delete the image view completely from video fragment to test if the problem comes from it .. but nothing change, the problem still exist

Comment: Can you enable "show layout boundaries" in developer options of your phone?, only to verify if you dont have other view overlay. Other tip:  open another activity to show the video (that is recommendly). Other one: change the framelayout in your root and put relative or linearlayout